# Mysterious Stackdriver error seems to suggest a bug with Stackdriver itself

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

For around three weeks now, I see these errors in Google Cloud console, for a Golang Appengine app:

```
{"errorReference":"ixWACIGAwIxxxxxxxxMCJu5TG-ykYAjIKGICAwIm7lMb7KWiBgMCJu5TG-ykD", "incident_id":"0.mz2xxxxxgg", "summary":"An internal error occurred while invoking the webhook."}
```

There is no other information associated with the event, other than `resource.type = "stackdriver_notification_channel"`

How could I debug this issue further? It's problematic, because I keep getting emails about errors in my logs.

That phrase does not occur in my source code, and also yields zero results when doing a Google search.

On the date where the errors started appearing, I have made no changes that would affect logging in my code.

It really does seem like an internal stackdriver error.

Comment: Hello @Mike, Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.<br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Looks like the cause of the issue is an incorrectly configured URL for the webhook endpoint.**

Maybe your webhook endpoint is configured to an internal URL and Google Cloud is not able to resolve that URL, thus you receive the failure message.

The webhook URL needs to be a publicly resolvable URL, not a private one, as it is described in [Webhook notifications aren't received](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/troubleshooting-alerts#webhook-private) and [Create and manage notification channels](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks) and it also needs to be accessible publicly. The `"/"` at the end depends on the application at the receiving end, it's not something Google Cloud controls, so we cannot know for sure.

**Check below what needs to be done to add to the URL to be publicly resolvable:**

This is a domain that Google Cloud does not control, so we do not know the specifics. Usually there needs to be at least an A entry in the authoritative domain name servers for `db.com domain`, that would resolve to an IP address. This is something your internal team should be able to help you with.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I investigated, and I believe that the cause for my errors was that an app that was receiving webhooks from alerts has crashed.

The error message could really be improved :)

Comment: Did it help you solve problems?.

Comment: I will have to wait one or two days before I'm certain, I will update this thread.

Comment: As there is no update on few days, out of curiosity I would like to understand from you whether the offered solution worked for you?.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that the program that was receiving my webhooks crashed. I fixed the segfault and restarted it, and the errors disappeared. Thank you for helping me.